# Jenkins | The Jenkins instance appears to be offline

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to run Jenkins on an Azure VM. The VM doesn't have internet access.

I'm getting "The Jenkins instance appears to be offline" when I hit Jenkins home page.

I want to know if Jenkins requires internet to run?

[image]

Comment: Yes, to be able to download and install plugins.

Comment: I've downloaded the jar from my machine and copied to the VM. There is no way to get internet on the VM. What option do I have? Any offline installation or something?

Comment: Yes, you can transfer the required plugins onto the VM and use them. See https://wiki.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=82674352#content/view/82674352 and specifically the comments section which describes how to disable jenkins to connect to internet to download plugins.